# How do I record a Nintendo Switch longer than 30 seconds and without a capture card?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I don't have a capture card, and I want to know how to make videos longer than 30 seconds on the Nintendo Switch.

Comment: You cannot within the built-in operating system; you would need some sort of external system or to modify the console, I am very sure.

Comment: I have an Xbox One

Comment: Sorry, what are you saying?

Comment: It's another powerful console that can stream certain stuff. You can connect any HDMI into it to stream the same image on their. I also have a PC. Don't know how to record from those, streaming my image at the same time.